# One meter accuracy for all of Continguous US: how is this possible?

Tags: coordinate-system

On the webpage about the projection [EPSG:5071](https://epsg.io/5071) (NAD83(HARN) / Conus Albers), it is said that the accuracy:

> Remarks: Accuracy 0.1 to 0.2m in California, 0.05-0.11 in Oregon,
>   elsewhere better than 0.05m.

The WKT says that it is a `Albers_Conic_Equal_Area` projection. But no projection can preserve distance everywhere. My questions are:

*How can a projection achieve sub-meter accuracy over such a large geographical extent?*

*What exactly does the "accuracy" (of 1 meter or 0.1 meter) referred to in epsg.io mean? Do they mean that distance is only off by no more than a meter in the contiguous US? If not, how much is distance off here in the worst case?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy values listed refer to the specified datum/coordinate transformation, not to the projection itself (the page you link to lists other transformations with differing accuracy).  It's nothing to do with whether a certain projection is distance, shape or area preserving.

From the [EPSG Registry](https://www.epsg-registry.org/help/xml/entities/Coordinate_Transformation.html):

> **Accuracy**
>
> Estimate(s) of the impact of this transformation on point accuracy.
> Gives position error estimates for target coordinates of this
> coordinate operation, assuming no errors in source coordinates. These
> accuracy estimates or position error estimates are given as plus or
> minus NN meters, where NN is the entered value.